# Array.Clear(new [] {1,2,3}, 0, 2) outputs [1,z2,z3]

Tags: c#, arrays

Edit: Changed System.Array.Clear(new[] {1,2,3}, 0, 2); to System.Array.Clear(numbers, 0, 2); but get the output [0, z0, z3] and was expecting [0,0,3]

I'm learning about C# and currently learning about arrays and Clear(). When trying to see what happens when using Clear(), I get this output:

[image]

I don't understand why this happens. Wasn't it supposed to be [0,0,3]?

My code looks like this:

**Program.cs**

```
namespace Introduction
{
    internal class Program
    {
        /* MAIN FUNCTION */
        public static void Main()
        {
            // RunControlFlow();
            RunArrays();
        }

        /* ARRAYS */
        public static void RunArrays()
        {
            // Var declaration
            var array = new Arrays.Array();

            array.Manipulation();
        }
    }
}
```

**Arrays.cs**

```
using System;

namespace Introduction.Arrays
{
    public class Array
    {

        public void Manipulation()
        {
            var numbers = new[] {1, 2, 3};
            System.Array.Clear(numbers, 0, 2);
            Console.WriteLine("Manipulation | Clearing from index 0 to 2: [{0}]", string.Join(",z", numbers));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not `Clear` `numbers`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not passing the `numbers` array to the `Clear` method, you are creating a new array that has the same elements, but it's a completely different reference and has nothing to do with `numbers`. That is why the values in `numbers` stays unchanged:

```
Array.Clear(numbers, 0, 2);
```

Comment: I see! I tried to input System.Array.Clear(numbers, 0, 2); now and I still get the same output [0,z0,z3]

Comment: @jubibanna that's not the same output though, previous output was "[1,z2,z3]" as in your screenshot.

Comment: I just generally don't understand where this 'z' comes from

Comment: @jubibanna that is what you give to string.Join. => `string.Join(",z",`

Comment: Ah for god sake. This string.Join line was messing it up, I was just trying to print all of the array on one line. It worked when I ran a foreach loop (showed 0 0 3).

I'm used to print(numbers) would give you the elements in the array and not just the type.

Anyway thank you so much for the fast help, Selman :-)